# 1997 ford e250 van oil in coolant but no coolant in oil

Tags: ford, oil-leak, e250

Recently my oil light keeps coming on. I checked the oil and there's none, but I don't see any leaks anywhere. It doesn't smoke, so I just added two quarts of oil. Light goes off and everything seems okay. Now oil light came on, pop the hood and I noticed milky white liquid all over where the coolant goes for the radiator. I checked the dipstick, no liquid in there at all. Would anybody have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: See my answer here.....https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/28946/16882

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be one of two things:

1. Blown head gasket. This is the most probable.
2. Cracked/broken oil cooler. This is more of a long shot. First, there has to be an oil cooler. Secondly, the oil cooler has to get cooled in the radiator. Thirdly, the cooler inside the radiator has to have sprung a leak.

All-in-all, you're going to have to take it to a shop, or at the very minimum, you'll need to have someone diagnose and fix it for you.